# How to send parameter to the bot in Facebook messenger

Tags: web, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to send any parameter into the bot in Facebook messenger like telegram? For example a link likes the following:

```
                           telegram.me/your_bot?start=XXXX
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is. `m.me` is a shortened URL service operated by Facebook that redirects users to a person, page, or bot in Messenger. The format of the link is `http://m.me/PAGE_NAME`, where `PAGE_NAME` is the handle of the Facebook page the bot is linked to.

A `m.me` link with an added parameter looks like this:

```
                              http://m.me/mybot?ref=myparam
```

The value of the `ref` parameter will be passed to the server via webhook.
Follow the details from [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/referral-params).

Comment: how to send more parameters?

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi If I understood your question, you can send multiple parameters the same as you do for "get" requests. Hence, you can separate parameters by "&" without any extra space in between.